# Writing a unit test for a method which depends on the return value of another method

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I'm writing a test cases to test for handleRequestsFailed and isObjectUndefinedOrEmpty in jest. But Since handleRequestsFailed  depends on the return value of isObjectUndefinedOrEmpty, I'm getting an error: throw new InternalServerErrorException(
         |               ^
       8 |             'Requests to get content failed!'
       9 |         );                                                       . Below is what I've in spec and ts file.

```
// ts file

export function handleRequestsFailed(res: any, res2?: any) {
    if (isObjectUndefinedOrEmpty(res) && isObjectUndefinedOrEmpty(res2)) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(
            'Requests to get content failed!'
        );
    }
}

export function isObjectUndefinedOrEmpty(obj: any) {
    return !obj || Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}

// spec file


import { handleRequestsFailed } from './shared-methods';

describe('Schedule Assistant', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
  });


  it('should return an error if isObjectUndefinedOrEmpty returns an undefined or empty object', () => {
    const res={}

    const assistant = new handleRequestsFailed(res);
    expect(assistant).toEqual({});
  });


});
```

Comment: why are you refering to it as `this`?

Comment: I've removed this. I has it there earlier before refactoring my code. but now it throws an error at throw new InternalServerErrorException.

Comment: Okay, now why are you using `new`? Also, your code is throwing the error, since the object `{}` is truthy and has no keys.